# wkhtmltopdf not preserving layout

Tags: html, css, pdf, layout, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to convert a simple HTML page with a custom grid layout (https://jsfiddle.net/nvhk3vp9/) to PDF using wkhtmltopdf 0.12.3 on Linux 64-bit with this simple command:

```
wkhtmltopdf index.html output.pdf
```

However, the resulting PDF file doesn't produce the desired result:
[image]

Am I missing something?

**Edit 1**:
After changing to `vh` and `vw` measure units the output has improved, however the result isn't yet as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a `vh`?

```
.col {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 25vh;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: I've changed all measure units to `vw` and `vh` (jsfiddle.net/nvhk3vp9/1). The PDF output has improved, however not yet the result I'm expecting (see edit 1).